# Can't create a class, Python3 (I'm a beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want some help for the following question.

I created this class.

```
>>>class CountFromBy:
       pass
```

But I can't create objects  from it.

I want to make an increment counter. 
So input these codes, but they doesn't work in the way I assume. Like this:

```
>>>c = CountFromBy()
>>>c
0
>>>c.increase()
>>>c.increase()
>>>c.increase()
>>>c
3
```

But, actually the result is:

```
>>>c = CountFromBy()
>>>c
<__main__.CountFromBy object at 0x042647F0>
```

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: Why do you expect evaluating `c` to show you `0`, instead of showing you a `CountFromBy` object? (And also, why do you expect to be able to call an `increase()` method on it when you haven't defined such a method anywhere?)

Comment: Please start by reading some basic tutorials, which SO is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking to make a subclass of `int`—something that acts just like an `int`, but has some extra behavior.

To do this, you use inheritance:

```
>>> class CountFromBy(int):
...     pass
```

Now, when you write `c = CountFromBy()`, it's a `CountFromBy` instance, which is also an `int` instance, so:

```
>>> c = CountFromBy()
>>> c
0
```

So far, you haven't added any new behavior, but if you want to do that, you just add methods:

```
>>> class CountFromBy(int):
...     def squared(self):
...         return CountFromBy(self * self)
>>> c = CountFromBy(3)
>>> c
3
>>> c.squared()
9
```

But if you want to add an `increase()` method, there's a big problem: `int` values are immutable. Since `CountFromBy` values are `int` values, they're also immutable. There's no way to write the class this way.

---

You might be looking for a class that *uses* an `int`, instead of *being* one. For that, you don't use inheritance, you just create a member:

```
>>> class CountFromBy:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.number = 0
```

If you want it to print out its `number` value, you can give it a `str` method:

```
>>> class CountFromBy:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.number = 0
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'CountFromBy({self.number})'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(self.number)
>>> c = CountFromBy()
>>> c
CountFromBy(0)
>>> print(c)
0
```

And now, you can add that `increase` method—it just replaces `self.number` with a new value:

```
>>> class CountFromBy:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.number = 0
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'CountFromBy({self.number})'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(self.number)
...     def increase(self):
...         self.number = self.number + 1
>>> c = CountFromBy()
>>> c.increase()
>>> c.increase()
>>> c.increase()
>>> print(c)
3
```

---

Finally, you might be looking for the best of both worlds—something that acts as much as possible like an `int` without actually being one, using an `int` for storage. This is just like [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userdict-objects) and friends from the standard library, so you can look at [the source for those classes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L957). As you can see, it's a bit more involved, so you probably don't want to try that yet. Plus, you'd have to decide what it means to act "as much as possible like an `int`", while at the same time being mutable.

Answer (score 2):

There you go.

```
class CountFromBy:
    def __init__(self, count=0):
        self.count = count
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.count)
    def increase(self):
        self.count += 1
```

e.g.

```
>>> c = CountFromBy() 
>>> c 
0        
>>> c.increase()
>>> c.increase() 
>>> c.increase()  
>>> c 
3
```

You can also initialze count by passing the initial value to the constructor.

```
>>> c = CountFromBy(5) 
>>> c 
5
>>> c.increase()
>>> c
6
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple class you can use

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("morty", 32)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```